# Define key in yup object from union string

Tags: typescript, yup

So I have a string union type that I used as key in an object. This is in typescript:

```
type Tag = "a" | "b" | "c"
type Obj = { [key in Tag]: number };
```

I'm trying to do that using Yup. The string union type is basic:

```
const tag = mixed<"a" | "b" | "c">().required();
```

But how to use it as key in the  yup object ?

```
const obj = obj({ [??]: number() });
```

Comment: Did you try [https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/130](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/130)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, a little verbose, but looks working for me.

```
import * as yup from "yup";

// generic helper
export type Writable<T> = { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K]; };

// key, built as enum
export const tagNames = ["A", "B", "C"] as const;
export type Tag = typeof tagNames[number];

// not readonly names, (easier foor looping on key)
export const writableTagNames = tagNames as Writable<typeof tagNames>;

// your Obj type, keyed with tag.
export type Obj = { [key in Tag]: number };

// your schema that would be the same for all entries
export const tagEntrySchema = yup.number().required("validation.required");
// with its type
export type TagEntrySchemaType = typeof tagEntrySchema;
//now the type of the full shape
export type TagEntryShapeType = { [key in Tag]: TagEntrySchemaType };
// type TagEntryShapeType = {
//     A: RequiredNumberSchema<number | undefined, AnyObject>;
//     B: RequiredNumberSchema<number | undefined, AnyObject>;
//     C: RequiredNumberSchema<...>;
// }

// build an instance of this shape, by looping on keys
export const allShapes: TagEntryShapeType = ((): TagEntryShapeType => {
    const result: Partial<TagEntryShapeType> = {};
    for (const key of writableTagNames) {
        result[key] = tagEntrySchema;
    }
    return result as TagEntryShapeType;
})();

// and create the yup object from this shape
export const ObjInputSchema = yup.object().shape(allShapes).noUnknown(true);

const candidates = [
    { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3 },
    { A: "romain", B: 2, C: 3 },
    { E: 1, B: 2, C: 3 },
    { A: 1, B: 2 },
];

const TestIt = async (): Promise<void> => {
    for (const cadidate of candidates) {
        const isvalid = await ObjInputSchema.isValid(cadidate);
        console.log((isvalid ? "Valid " : "Invalid ") + JSON.stringify(cadidate, null, 2));
    }
};
TestIt();

// Valid {
//   "A": 1,
//   "B": 2,
//   "C": 3
// }
// Invalid {
//   "A": "romain",
//   "B": 2,
//   "C": 3
// }
// Invalid {
//   "E": 1,
//   "B": 2,
//   "C": 3
// }
// Invalid {
//   "A": 1,
//   "B": 2
// }
```